# How To Pass Class As Params to Function

Tags: c#, function, parameters

How can I pass the Parameter to a function. for example

```
 public void GridViewColumns(params ClassName[] pinputparamter)
 {
 }
```

and Class is as given below

```
public Class ClassName
{
     public string Name{get;set;}
     public int RecordID{get;set;}
}
```

can anyone has idea?

Comment: Please precise what you are trying to do. What is wrong with this example (despite the "Class" keyword instead of "class") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`params` means that the method can accept any number of parameters of type `ClassName`. Example of calling it with two instances of ClassName:

```
GridViewColumns(new ClassName(), new ClassName());
```

or

```
ClassName a = new ClassName();
ClassName b = new ClassName();
ClassName c = new ClassName();
GridViewColumns(a, b, c);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you have to create an object of the class in your main().

```
ClassName myObject = new ClassName();
```

then you can pass it as a parameter in your function.

```
GridViewColumns(myObject);
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pass instances of `ClassName` as Array:

```
ClassName[] arr = new ClassName[]{new ClassName(), new ClassName()};
GridViewColumns(arr);
```

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28VS.100%29.aspx).